# How can I crawl all the <td> contents?(python3.6)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

When using the python3 and the BeautifulSoup to get the specified content from the web,I couldn't get all the information in  "td".

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getHTMLText(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
        return r.text
    except:
        return ''
def main():
    try:
        url = "http://baike.hrhrs.com/index.php?doc-view-3967.html"
        html = getHTMLText(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        # print(soup.prettify())

        for tag in soup.find_all('h1',class_='title_thema'):
            name = tag.find('span', id='doctitle').get_text()

        # the first one
        table1 = soup.find('table',attrs={'id': 'jqe-table-0'})
        tr = table1.find_all('tr')
        for trr in tr:
            td = trr.findAll('td')
            print(td)
```

Here's the output

```
    [<td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A1：</strong>A2</td>, <td class="jg" style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 10px; border-bottom: none;"></td>, <td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"A3：</strong>A4</td>]
[<td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A5：</strong>A6</td>, <td class="jg" style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 10px; border-bottom: none;"></td>, <td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A7：</strong>A8</td>]
[<td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A9：</strong>A10</td>, <td class="jg" style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 10px; border-bottom: none;"></td>, <td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A11：</strong>A12</td>]
[<td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A13：</strong>A14</td>, <td class="jg" style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 10px; border-bottom: none;"></td>, <td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A15：</strong>A16</td>]
[<td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A17：</strong>A18</td>, <td class="jg" style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 10px; border-bottom: none;"></td>, <td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A19：</strong>A20</td>]
[<td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A21：</strong>A22</td>, <td class="jg" style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 10px; border-bottom: none;"></td>, <td style="padding: 2px 0px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; line-height: 18px; background: rgb(252, 253, 255); width: 350px; border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);"><strong style="display: block; line-height: 22px; vertical-align: baseline; zoom: 1; width: 80px; float: left; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">A23：</strong>A24</td>]
```

I use the code:

```
print(td[0].text)
```

and the results are:

```
A1：A2
A5：A6
A9：A10
A13：A14
A17：A18
A21：A22
```

I want to get all contents in the "td" such as "A3:A4" and son on.
How can I change my code to get all the contens.Hope for your response!

Answer (score 1):

According to my original code,just get the results like this:

```
中文名：柳公权
别名：诚悬
出生地：京兆华原（今陕西铜川市耀州区）
民族：汉族
出生年月：公元778年
职业：书法家
```

Changing the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getHTMLText(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
        return r.text
    except:
        return ''

def main():
    try:
       for count in range(100,1000):
           url = "http://baike.hrhrs.com/index.php?doc-view-"+str(count)+".html"
           html = getHTMLText(url)
           soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
           # print(soup.prettify())

           for tag in soup.find_all('h1', class_='title_thema'):
               name = tag.find('span', id='doctitle').get_text()
               n[0] = name;

           tr = soup.find_all('tr')
           for trr in tr:
               tdlist = trr.find_all('td')
               for i in range(len(tdlist)):
                  print(str(tdlist[i].text))       
    except:
        print("error")

    print("successfully！")


main()
```

Results:

```
中文名：柳公权
中文名：柳公权
别名：诚悬
籍贯：唐朝京兆华原（今陕西耀县）
出生地：京兆华原（今陕西铜川市耀州区）
性别：男
民族：汉族
国籍：中国
......
```

All contents is available.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, running step-by-step within Jupyter Notebook, I got

```
中文名：柳公权
别名：诚悬
出生地：京兆华原（今陕西铜川市耀州区）
民族：汉族
出生年月：公元778年
职业：书法家
```

Do you mean this?

Here are my changes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://baike.hrhrs.com/index.php?doc-view-3967.html"

def main():
  global url

  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  tags = soup.find_all('h1', class_='title_thema')

  for tag in tags:
    name = tag.find('span', id='doctitle').get_text()
    print(name)

  table1 = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'jqe-table-0'})
  tr = table1.find_all('tr')
  for trr in tr:
    td = trr.findAll('td')
    print(td[0].text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: I got the "中文名：柳公权". I guess the problem is due to decoding some Chinese text. I have similar issue if I run the code entirely within Jupyter notebook but no so if I ran it step-by-step or in dos prompt.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but there' still  other information I couldn't  get. such as"中文名:柳公权   籍贯：唐朝京兆华原（今陕西耀县.....",it locate in the second "td".

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://baike.hrhrs.com/index.php?doc-view-3967.html"
res = requests.get(url)
data = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
x for x in data.find_all('td')
    print (x.text)
```